# Blank screen after boot on Radeon R9 280X

Tags: 16.04, drivers, radeon

My graphic card is AMD Radeon R9 280X and because Ubuntu 16.04 does not have `fglrx` I am using Oibaf's graphic drivers. Everything was working fine, but from today after boot I see white screen with random colors:
[image: artefacts]
[image: zoom]
I do not have idea what caused this, because I don't remember doing updates or modifying files.

I found temporary workaround: setting `nomodeset` in grub options, but this results in very low performance.

What should I do?

`Xorg.0.log`: https://pastebin.com/TMbzM3er

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem (as in andrzej1_1's images) and removing and purging the oibaf repositories helped:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

I didn't want to stay on the generic drivers so I tried installing PadokaPPA, and choose the unstable branch, which had the exact same problem as oibaf, so I uninstalled that and tried the stable branch:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

After reboot the problem was gone.

*An important note when trying these things is to remember to actually do the apt upgrade after switching PPA, which basically is the reason I added this answer.*

Answer (score 2):

It is working now! I have done few things, but I am not sure which one fixed problem:

- Switching from Oibaf to Padoka Stable Mesa PPA:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
  $ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
  $ sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Clearing cache:

  ```
  $ sudo rm -fr .cache/*
  ```
- Reconfiguring unity-greeter:

  ```
  $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity-greeter
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the AMDGPU PRO driver and the recent update to kernel 4.10 broke the system.
I understand that you are using Oibaf's graphic drivers, but are you sure that they are compatible with a potential kernel update?
Also I had similar issue with another PC/AMD card and booting in terminal and uninstalling/reinstalling the driver in command line solved the issue. Worth a try?
The new generic driver coming with the new kernel works fine for me.
Rv

Comment: AMDGPU-PRO is not compatibile with `Radeon R9 280X`, so I am using Oibaf's drivers. I tried reinstalling unity, xorg, drivers but nothing helped. I will try to boot with old kernel and let you know.